# Best practices for using Azure CLI in a Azure VM via Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-storage, azure-cli

I am pretty new with Azure.
I have a Jenkins Cluster. Jobs are launched in slaves. Slaves are Azure VM (Ubuntu).

I need to run some Azure CLI commands for deploying files to an Azure Storage Blob.

I think I need to have an identity (user?) allowed to use Azure CLI inside the VM.

Maybe can I create a specific user for Jenkins only?
Is a Managed Identity could use Azure CLI as well?

I wonder what is the best way accomplishing this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Please create a Service Principal either using the Portal or Azure CLI.

To create the service principal using CLI, please use below command :

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name ServicePrincipalName
```

Please  refer for more  details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli

To create service principal using Portal,

Go to Azure Active Directory --> App Registrations --> New Registration --> Complete the form --> Register

[image]

Go to your Storage Account --> Select Access Control (IAM)--> Add Role Assignment --> Under Role, select Storage Account Contributor --> Under Select, search for your Service Principal --> Click on Save

[image]

Now, the service principal will have Storage Account contributor access. You can deploy the files to Azure Storage using CLI.

Go to Azure Active Directory --> App Registrations --> Search for your Service Principal and click on it.

Please note the Application ID, Tenant ID.

Go to Clients & secrets --> Click on New Client Secret --> Fill the form and click Ok.

Note the Client Secret.

Inside the VM, please use below command to login to Azure using your Service Principal

```
az login --service-principal -u <app-id> -p <client-secret> --tenant <tenant-id>
```

Now you can deploy the files to the Azure Storage account from the VM using CLI.

To upload a file to your Storage Account, please use below CLI command :

```
az storage blob upload --account-name StorageAccountName --container-name ContainerName --name fileName --file sourceFileName
```

Comment: Very clear, you helped a lot. Thank you very much.